# How group by a query by family code

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I should write a query to calculate the sum of a column where the reason code like a number. So I have this table

TableX:

```
 ------------------------
| ReasoneCode | Duration |
|------------------------|
| 201         | 27512    |
| 202         | 4372     |
| 100         | 10322    |
| 301.12      | 1        |
| 302.06      | 34       |
| 305         | 12       |
 ------------------------
```

Now I want a result like this:

```
 ------------------------
| ReasoneCode | Duration |
|------------------------|
| 200         | 31884    |
| 100         | 10322    |
| 300         | 47       |
 ------------------------
```

So I try to write this query but not found correctly

```
SELECT ReasonCode, SUM(Duration)
FROM TableX    
GROUP BY ReasonCode
```

Can you help me?

---

I try to use this solution. 
With this query I remove all '.' from the first column

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(replace(ReasonCode, '.', ''), (CHARINDEX('.', replace(ReasonCode, '.', ''), 1) + 4)) AS DECIMAL(14, 0)) as Data, SUM(Duration)
FROM TableX
GROUP BY CAST(LEFT(replace(ReasonCode, '.', ''), (CHARINDEX('.', replace(ReasonCode, '.', ''), 1) + 4)) AS DECIMAL(14, 0))
```

Now I try to write an another query for group by result from reasoneCode Family.
The result of this query is:

```
 ------------------------
| ReasoneCode | Duration |
|------------------------|
| 201         | 27512    |
| 202         | 4372     |
| 100         | 10322    |
| 30112       | 1        |
| 30206       | 34       |
| 305         | 12       |
 ------------------------
```

I could put this result into temporary table, then select from this temporary table

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST(ReasonCode as decimal(8,2)) as int) / 100 * 100 as roundedCode,
    SUM(Duration)
FROM @TemporaryTable    
GROUP BY CAST(CAST(ReasonCode as decimal(8,2)) as int) / 100 * 100
```

Now the result is this:

```
     ------------------------
    | ReasoneCode | Duration |
    |------------------------|
    | 200         | 31884    |
    | 100         | 10322    |
    | 3000        | 35       |
    | 305         | 12       |
     ------------------------
```

There is only one error, it not group by 300 and 3000.

Comment: After 30 posts please learn to format your questions properly.

Comment: What you mean by `like a number`? Which type of `ReasoneCode`?

Comment: The ReasoneCode column is a NVARCHAR column but contains value as 301,302,301.12,301.13...

Comment: And what about the first part of my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(ReasonCode as int) / 100 * 100 as roundedCode, SUM(Duration)
FROM TableX    
GROUP BY roundedCode
```

Comment: Thanks you but there are a column with the value is 302.12 or 303.06 then your query not found

Comment: Then cast the value to `int` first like I do in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group by the multiples of hundred and both the columns are numeric, this is how it can be done.

SELECT round(round(ReasonCode)/100)*100 as roundedCode, SUM(Duration)
FROM TableX
GROUP BY roundedCode

Comment: Thanks you but there are a column with the value is 302.12 or 303.06 then your query not found

Comment: Okay. I assumed the Reasoncode column as a whole number. I have edited the answer to work for the decimal. please try the updatedquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST(ReasonCode as decimal(15,5)) as int) / 100 * 100 as roundedCode,
    SUM(Duration)
FROM TableX    
GROUP BY roundedCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If ReasonCode is NUMERIC datatype

```
SELECT (ReasonCode-(ReasonCode%100)), SUM(Duration)
FROM #Table    
GROUP BY (ReasonCode-(ReasonCode%100))
```

If ReasonCode is NVARCHAR

```
SELECT (CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,6),ReasonCode)-(CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,6),ReasonCode)%100)), SUM(Duration)
FROM #Table    
GROUP BY (CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,6),ReasonCode)-(CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,6),ReasonCode)%100))
```